# Format shell script output

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to format my script output in tabular format something like this:

```
Data:        11001,4071 | 10008,4578 | 10500,2100 ...
==================================================
20160720     55454         545454       55454
```

somehow i am able to achieve it but script asks for password and prints `catrunner --> Using standard unix daf factory libpal-daf inline.`

like:

```
  Date:     11001,4071 | 10008,4578 | 10500,2100 | 40000,4021 | 10003,1102 | 11001,9230 | 10001,1001 | 40000,4020 | 10001,1102 | 10008,4569 | 10008,4568 | 10003,1200 | 40000,4006    
======================================================================================================================================================================================
    20160720    Password: // for switch user, how can i ommit password request?
    su: incorrect password
    catrunner --> Using standard unix daf factory libpal-daf //How can i get ride of this line?
    13116
    catrunner --> Using standard unix daf factory libpal-daf
    9167
    catrunner --> Using standard unix daf factory libpal-daf
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
DT=`date +%Y%m%d`
Yesterday=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
CODES="$(< error_codes.txt)" 
divider==============
divider1=$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider$divider

header="\n %-10s %8s %10s %21s\n"
width=43

echo "  Date:    "  `sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ | /; ta' error_codes.txt`
echo $divider1;
printf  "%s\t" $DT

su - adv 
cd /advdata/datashareB/FFFF/continuousDownstream/` echo $Yesterday`
for CODE in $CODES; do
  EventType=$(echo $CODE | cut -c1-5)
  ErrorCode=$(echo $CODE | cut -c7-10)
  eventExport -printEvents -file Run_`echo $fileName`*_*.tar -filter "ErrorCode=`echo $ErrorCode`;EventType=`echo $EventType`"  -names -silent | wc -l
done
printf "$s\n"
```

Comment: Is the `su` what is generating the password request? (that all I can see). If you want to eliminate `su` asking the user for a password, the general was is to make the user a member of the `wheel` group (or some other limited group you want passwordless access to `su` for, then depending on your distro, most will allow additional entries in `/etc/pam.d/su` to allow `su` without a password through `pam_wheel.so`.

Comment: That's fine.. but what about output formatting?

Comment: If setup to use without a password, just `su - adv &>/dev/null` to get rid of the response from `su`